# HttpGet HttpPost method deviation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have two identical methods.

My [HttpGet] method returns a list of all data for my KPI's Model.

My [HttpPost] version needs to return a list of data within a date range for my KPI's model.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ViewDepartment (int id = 0)
{
   // populate the IPACS_kpiHistory with all available data in the department
var kpi = model.IPACS_Department.IPACS_Functions.SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Processes).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Procedures).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_KPIS);

foreach (var item in kpi)
{
    model.IPACS_KPIS.Add(item);
}
   return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewDepartment (int id, System.DateTime startDate, system.DateTime endDate)
{
   // populate the IPACS_kpiHistory with all available data in the department
var kpi = model.IPACS_Department.IPACS_Functions.SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Processes).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_Procedures).SelectMany(m => m.IPACS_KPIS);

foreach (var item in kpi)
{
    model.IPACS_KPIS.Add(item);
}
   return View(model);
}
```

On the view page I need to display a list of every single KPI (found in IPACS_KPIS) I then sum the data for each KPI (found in IPACS_kpiHistory).

Here is my view page section:

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.IPACS_KPIS)
{
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>
            @item.name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Select(m => m.startAmount).Sum()
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Select(m => m.completedAmount).Sum()
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Select(m => m.endAmount).Sum()
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

How do I correctly filter out the data for the [HttpPost] and find values between the `startDate` and `endDate`?

The only way I can think of doing it is adding 2 properties to my model a `startDate` and an `endDate` and using those on the razor page but trying to see if it is possible to do all that work in the controller and keep the razor page clean.

Criteria:

Must display every single KPI (even if it has no data (currently works like this) )
Must filter out items not between the `daterange` in the `[HttpPost]` method.

Comment: If you don't need the other KPI's you can add a Where(m => m.Date ...) to the line that starts with var kpi =

Comment: @NickBray sadly I have to show the KPI's that do have items in the kpiHistory table and KPI's that do not yet have an entry in the kpiHistory table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. POST should only be used for posting data back to server. "GET" method should be used when the form processing is "idempotent", and in those cases only. As a simplification, we might say that "GET" is basically for just getting (retrieving) data whereas "POST" may involve anything, like storing or updating data, or ordering a product, or sending E-mail.

Why not do the following (this approach will give a generic functionality that takes care of all type of filtering/searching etc):

- Use HttpGet without any params => would give you default list
- Use HttpGet with params (filters) => would give you a filtered list

Create a custom filter:

```
public class SearchAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        #region Public Methods and Operators

        /// <summary>
        /// Overrides method OnActionExecuting, fires before every controller action is executed. Method retrives list search parameters from current url and saves them in
        /// SearchParams base controller dictionary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext">
        /// The filter Context.
        /// </param>
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            foreach (string key in filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
            {
                if ((key != null) && key.StartsWith("f_"))
                {

                        filterContext.Controller.ViewData[key] =
                            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[key].ToLower();

                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

So anything that comes via Url with "f_" will be treated as a filter parameter.

Decorate your controller with the FilterAttribute you've created above:

```
[Search]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var qs = this.ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString
   ....
}
```

"qs" holds now your querystring that you can parse and depending on filters there you return the correct list.

Comment: I'm sure this works perfectly, but implementing it to me seems a bit hard.  I'm still fairly new and there are several things here I'm not familiar with.  I will work on trying it, but gonna have to do some learning which is never a bad thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

To sum the values within a certain range, just add a Where clause:

```
@item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Where(m => m.date >= Model.MinDate && m.date <= Model.MaxDate)
    .Sum(m => m.startAmount)
```

Comment: I tried this and it is returning no data now.  which is odd because there is data, but when I try to filter it out by data nothing exists according to the page.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by another poster you should use Get for both of these controller methods.  It's not a big deal, but it is the normal convention.  Then you would have one method that is a get and takes id, start date, end date.

If you use just get or both get and post, you can still solve this problem without any logic being on the view (since it shouldn't be there).

Add start date and end date to the model.  Then set those properties or variables in the controller.  Then create a method on the model Model.GetFilteredKPIS() this method returns all the KPIS that are between start date and end date in the model.

Then the razor will be clean:

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.GetFilteredKPIS())
{
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>
            @item.name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Select(m => m.startAmount).Sum()
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Select(m => m.completedAmount).Sum()
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.IPACS_kpiHistory.Select(m => m.endAmount).Sum()
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your foreach loop in you post method to something like this

```
foreach (var item in kpi)
{
    if (startdate <= item.date && item.date <= enddate)
    {
        model.IPACS_KPIS.Add(item);
    }
}
```

You will have to change it to use the relevant properties of your objects.

Comment: This will only add the items that have an entry in the kpiHistory table if I'm not mistaken right?  I need it to show every single KPI (every row in the KPI table) and then for the post method I still need to show every KPI but then filter out the data in the kpihistory by date.

Comment: So for example my KPI tables lists out 40 different KPI's.  My kpiHistory table shows all of the data for each individual KPI.  I sum this data and show it on my view page.  If the KPI has had no work done on it in the kpihistory table I still need to show it, if it does have work done on it I need to sum only the data between the dates.  Think that is worded better.

Comment: @JamesWilson Your question is missing a lot of relevant code and information.  First, you have some model object that we have no idea how it is created or what is even in it.  Second, I have no clue what a KPI is or what KPI History is or how this stuff comes out of your DB, etc.  Without this information, all we can do is guess how to help you.  Please edit your question to add more detail.